# Understanding the inner workings of seekg() and tellg()

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm learning about file I/O for a project I am undertaking. Using seekg() and tellg() will be necessary for me, so I started researching. While troubleshooting my code (because the file isn't reading in data exactly how I wanted) I tested the following code:

```
fileObj.seekg(fileObj.tellg(),std::ios::beg);
```

But, this causes an endless loop. This code in a certain position will cause the endless loop but the other two identical lines in other areas have no effect. tellg() should be the current location and so changing the current location to the current location shouldn't have any effect. But that is obviously not the case, and I'd like to understand why so i can use tellg() and seekg() more effectively.

```
std::unordered_map <unsigned, Player> genRoster(String rosterFile)
{
    std::ifstream fileObj;
    fileObj.open(rosterFile.c_str(), std::ios::in);

    if (!fileObj.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "rosterFile could not be opened." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    String teamName;
    teamName.getLine(fileObj,'\n',0);

    //skip the # of players line
    long long fileLocation;
    if(fileObj.tellg() != -1)
        fileLocation = fileObj.tellg() + 1;
    fileObj.seekg(fileLocation);

    std::unordered_map <unsigned, Player> roster;

    while(!fileObj.eof())
    {
        fileObj.seekg(fileObj.tellg(),std::ios::beg); //no effect
        unsigned ID;
        fileObj.seekg(fileObj.tellg(),std::ios::beg); //no effect
        String playerName;
        fileObj >> ID >> playerName;
        //fileObj.seekg(fileObj.tellg(),std::ios::beg); //endless loop!
        std::cout << "ID: " << ID << std::endl;
        std::cout << "name: " << playerName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "team: " << teamName << std::endl;

        //Player player(ID, playerName, teamName);  
        //roster.emplace(ID, player);
        // ...
        //The rest of the code is incomplete / irrelevant
    }
    return roster;
}
```

This is the file I am reading in:

```
The Cowboys
3
1 Bob
2 Sally
3 Sam
```

I am using my own string class, so in case the overloaded >> operator is a part of the issue here is the implementation:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, String& inputVar)
{
    inputVar.stringLen = 0;
    inputVar.stringVar = new char[inputVar.stringLen + 1];
    inputVar.stringVar[inputVar.stringLen] = '\0';

    long long lenCounter = 0;

    char inputChar;
    while (input.get(inputChar))
    {
        // end-of-input delimiter (change according to your needs)
        if (inputChar == '\n') break;

        // if buffer is exhausted, reallocate it twice as large
        if (lenCounter == inputVar.stringLen)
        {
            //this is needed for me bc i chose stringlen to be w/o null term.
            //so starts at 0. so *2 would do nothing
            if (inputVar.stringLen == 0) inputVar.stringLen++;
            inputVar.stringLen *= 2;
            char *newString = new char[inputVar.stringLen];
            strcpy(newString, inputVar.stringVar);
            delete[] inputVar.stringVar;
            inputVar.stringVar = newString;
        }
        // store input char
        inputVar.stringVar[lenCounter] = inputChar;

        lenCounter++;
    }
    inputVar.stringVar[lenCounter] = '\0';
    return input;
}
```

Please forgive any post etiquette mistakes. Let me know and I will edit. I read from Stack Overflow all the time, but this is my first post.

Thank you.

Comment: You opened the file in text mode, and using`seekg()` and `tellg()` on such files will not work as you would expect them to.  Try opening the file with an added `std::ios::binary` flag nstead.

Comment: Thank you. That was definitely a source of my issues.